# Toggle Function open by default

Tags: jquery

I have a Function that toggle(open and Hide a Div ) by clicking : " Show / Hide Filter " text .

Here is the Function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});

</script>
```

What I am wanting to Do is make this Div by default open  then click to open or Hide . Now this is by Default Hidden . Is there Solution For this ?

Comment: Yes, stop hiding it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `$(".slidingDiv").hide();` that hides the sliding div so that it is shown by default.

Answer (score 0):

*Now this is by Default Hidden* ? Not *by-default* This is because you are hiding it with this -

```
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
```

Remove that line and it should show as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".slidingDiv").show(); // <-- This does the trick
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });    
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  //$(".slidingDiv").hide(); <---- should be out. 
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
  });
 </script>
```